# Thinkpad X61 Tablet Wacom Stylus

Tags: thinkpad, wacom

When I test drove Maverick on the USB drive the stylus and buttons worked perfectly. Now that I have installed Maverick, the stylus buttons are switched. Is there a way to get the config file that is used by Ubuntu when it is demoing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkWiki) is a good site for setting up Linux on Thinkpads.  There [page on the stylus](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Wacom_Serial_Tablet_PC_Stylus) may be a good place to start.